# How to set image of navigation item (like send button) in MFMailComposer Controller

Tags: iphone

I want to set image of navigation item (send button) in MFMailComposer Controller,and i write code this..

[picker.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sendbutton.png"]];

but it's not change it.I change becoz my send button not working using this code..

```
   UIBarButtonItem *sendBtn=picker.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem;
   UIButton *btn2=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
   btn2.frame=CGRectMake(280, 2, 55, 30);
   [btn2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images (2).jpeg"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   btn2.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
   [btn2 addTarget:sendBtn.target action:sendBtn.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   UIBarButtonItem *btnTemp2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn2];
   [[[[picker viewControllers]lastObject] navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:btnTemp2];
```

But my cancel button have code

`UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn= picker.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem;
     UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     btn1.frame = CGRectMake(20, 2, 60, 30);
   [btn1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_tellAFriend_cancel@2x.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btn1.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [btn1 addTarget:cancelBtn.target action:cancelBtn.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    UIBarButtonItem *btnTemp = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn1];

    [[[[picker viewControllers] lastObject] navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:btnTemp];
    [btnTemp release];`

It work fine

Answer (score 1):

MFMailComposeViewController send button cannot be modified and should not be changed according to apple

The only thing you can do is change MFMailComposeViewController navigation bar tint color which will also change send button color

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [[picker navigationBar] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Comment: I write code already as above but my send button not call mailComposeController method

Comment: But it is possible,i see in Instagram project,in itunes app store. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instagram/id389801252?mt=8

Comment: But sir my requiedment is set image on navbar and both two button and work fine as MFMailComposerController button send and cancell,tint color only change button color.i set all it but my cancel button work fine but send no work here.

Comment: Instagram is not using mfmailcomposer it is sending mail through other process

Comment: but it's sending look is same as MFMailComposer.if it is other then tell me what can i do this.

Comment: check this link,it might help    http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/checkout

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar_logo.png"]];
[imageView sizeToFit];
imageView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                              UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
UIBarButtonItem *loadingView = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];

loadingView.target = self;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = loadingView;

[imageView release];
[loadingView release];
```

Comment: I write code already as above but my send button not call mailComposeController method.